# Javadoc with Gradle : Don't get the libraries while running javadoc task

Tags: javadoc, libraries, gradle

I am new to gradle, and I am trying to run javadoc using gradle. I have followed the [gradle javadoc page](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/javadoc/Javadoc.html), so I have added my next task in the build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'java'


task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
source = sourceSets.main.allJava  }
```

My problem is, that none of the libraries of my project are added, so I get a lot of errors like the next one:

```
MyClass.java:7: package net.sf.oval.constraint does not exist import net.sf.oval.constraint.NotNull;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time,

Rafael

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to configure the class path of your Javadoc task. Something like:

```
myJavadocs {
    classpath = configurations.compile
}
```

For further configuration options, see the [DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html).

Comment: Tx, but could you explain a bit more/give a fuller example?  the DSL ref is not at all explanatory to someone new to Gradle (and new to Groovy).  I want to do a simple thing: exclude the dependencies from the Javadoc and stop the imports from them preventing the creation of the Javadoc for my app classes...